# MapBox API exclusive layer switcher

Tags: javascript, jquery, mapbox

I have thoroughly searched MapBox support and Stack Overflow for an answer on how to create an exclusive layer switcher using the latest [MapBox API](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api/v1.6.1/) (1.6.1 as of now). Exclusive in this case means that only 1 layer can be visible/active at a time. I do not want to use the Leaflet Layers Control for design reasons.

With a little help, I have come up with this example, which almost works:

http://bl.ocks.org/sarahkhank/0e5d81998d2d0876856c

For some reason, adding and removing the gridControl breaks the loop. If you use this structure to just add/remove the tileLayer with no gridLayer or gridControl, it works fine. But when you add the grid elements, the last element in the array doesn't show up and messes up the rest of the loop. (In this case 'far'.)

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening? This type of layer switcher is often asked about on MapBox support, so I'm sure many people would be happy to see this come to life. Thanks for your help!!

Posting full code here at the bottom in case my bl.ocks link ever breaks.

```
<html>  
<head>
<title>DC Zoning Map</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src='http://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v1.6.1/mapbox.js'></script>
    <link href='http://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v1.6.1/mapbox.css' rel='stylesheet' />
</head>
  <body>
  <style>
#zoning-map-container {
    position:relative;
    float: right;
    display: inline;
}

#map_zoning {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    width:45%;
    min-width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    right:20px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #bbb;
  }

#map-ui-zoning {
  position:relative;
  float: left;
  list-style:none;
  margin:0;padding:0;
  left: -20px;
  }

#map-ui-zoning a {
  font-family:  'Carrois Gothic', sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 400;
  background:#FFF;
  color:#5698D0;
  float: left;
  margin:0;
  border:1px solid #BBB;
  border-width: 1px 1px 1px 0;
  max-width:100px;
  padding:8px;
  text-decoration:none;
  }

#map-ui-zoning li {
    display: inline;
  }

#map-ui-zoning a:hover { background:#ECF5FA; }

#map-ui-zoning li:last-child a {
  border-bottom-width:1px;
  -webkit-border-radius:0 3px 3px 0;
          border-radius:0 3px 3px 0;
  }

#map-ui-zoning li:first-child a {
border-left-width: 1px;
  -webkit-border-radius:3px 0 0 3px;
          border-radius:3px 0 0 3px;
        }

#map-ui-zoning a.active {
  background:#5698D0;
  border-color:#5698D0;
  border-top-color:#BBB;
  color:#FFF;
  }
  .map-tooltip .zone {
    font-size: 10px;
    line-height: 13px;
    font-weight: bold;
    }
   .map-tooltip .desc {
    font-size: 10px;
    line-height: 13px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    } 
   .map-tooltip .focus {
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    }  
   .map-tooltip .info {
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 16px;
    } 

</style>
<div id='zoning-map-container'>
        <ul id='map-ui-zoning'>
          <li><a href="#" data-name="stories" class="active">Maximum Stories</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" data-name="height">Maximum Height</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" data-name="far">Maximum FAR</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id='map_zoning'></div>
  </div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var map = L.mapbox.map('map_zoning');

    var stamenLayer = L.tileLayer('https://stamen-tiles-{s}.a.ssl.fastly.net/toner-lite/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
      attribution: 'Map tiles by <a href="http://stamen.com">Stamen Design</a>, under <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0">CC BY 3.0</a>. Data by <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a>, under <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0">CC BY SA</a>.'
    }).addTo(map);
    map.setView([38.908, -77.029], 11);

    var ui = document.getElementById('map-ui-zoning');

    var stories = L.mapbox.tileLayer('sarah.28n6ogvi');
        var storiesGrid = L.mapbox.gridLayer('sarah.28n6ogvi');
        var storiesGridControl = L.mapbox.gridControl(storiesGrid, {follow: false});

    var height = L.mapbox.tileLayer('sarah.ofjsv2t9');
        var heightGrid = L.mapbox.gridLayer('sarah.ofjsv2t9');
        var heightGridControl = L.mapbox.gridControl(heightGrid, {follow: false});

    var far = L.mapbox.tileLayer('sarah.2w9x80k9');
        var farGrid = L.mapbox.gridLayer('sarah.2w9x80k9');
        var farGridControl = L.mapbox.gridControl(farGrid, {follow: false});

    var layers = [{
        'name': 'stories',
        'layer': stories,
    'gridLayer': storiesGrid,
    'gridControl': storiesGridControl
      },
      {
        'name': 'height',
        'layer': height,
    'gridLayer': heightGrid,
    'gridControl': heightGridControl
      },
      {
        'name': 'far',
        'layer': far,
    'gridLayer': farGrid,
    'gridControl': farGridControl
      }
    ];

    $(document).ready(function(layer){
    map.addLayer(stories);
          map.addLayer(storiesGrid);
          map.addControl(storiesGridControl);
    });

    $('#map-ui-zoning li a').on('click', function() {
      $('#map-ui-zoning li a').removeClass('active');
      var $el = $(this);
      layers.forEach(function(layer) {
        if ($el.data('name') !== layer['name']){
          map.removeLayer(layer['layer']);
          map.removeLayer(layer['gridLayer']);
          map.removeControl(layer['gridControl']);
        }
        else {
          map.addLayer(layer['layer']);
          map.addLayer(layer['gridLayer']);
          map.addControl(layer['gridControl']);
          $el.addClass('active');
        }
      });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that when you call  map.removeControl(layer['gridControl']) or more generally map.removeLayer you dont test if the layer is already added to the map   because otherwise it mapboxjs will try to delete an element that does not exist and this is where your code gets broken  .

```
        if ($el.data('name') !== layer['name'])
```

needs to become

```
    if ($el.data('name') !== layer['name'] && map.hasLayer(layer))
```

of course you need to change your else statement accordingly .

here is your example running 
http://bl.ocks.org/radproject/31c48b1a7610e353d495